# Coding an integrated Bayesian model with a mix of stochastic and deterministic inputs

Tags: r, prediction, bayesian, jags, stochastic

## The Problem

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement a Bayesian Framework for a predictive model that contains many deterministic inputs mixed with a few stochastic inputs. Conceptually the problem seems easy, but from a coding standpoint I am unsure how to specify this model as an integrated unit in JAGS/BUGS language (e.g., the entire equation described within a single JAGS/BUGS model).

**The Way Forward**
I have been told that the entire analysis should be within the confines of a single JAGS/BUGS model rather than as separate JAGS models from which 100,000 data points simulated from a Posterior Predictive Distribution (PPD) of each are input into the main equation.

Perhaps all that is required is to copy and paste all the JAGS code into one place and add the larger equation?

## The Equation

**The basic components of this equation are:**

> *Outcome = probability of an event (in blue) * rate of exposure (in green) * ability to avoid that event (in orange)*

**The full equation is:**

[image]

Where variables in red (G, P*Q+R, and avoid) are stochastic, with the P*Q+R being a linear regression that helps predict annual variability in exposure. I have empirical data for each of these variables and need to use a Bayesian framework (or other probabilistic approach) to model the outcome of this equation based on this combination of deterministic and stochastic inputs.

## Initial Attempt

While I am a fan of Bayesian approaches in theory and am working to actualize this approach, my training to date has been more focused on resampling procedures. As such, the most logical thing to do seemed to be to generate separate JAGS code for each of the stochastic inputs and then use each of the saved steps in the MCMC chain for each parameter (s=100,000) to plug into the likelihood function and generate a dataset from the Posterior Predictive Distribution (PPD) to serve as an input for the larger equation.

Although the model is not integrated into a single Jags code unit, mathematically it seems that this the proper approach given the answers by @baruuum to @Fred L.'s question about Understanding Bayesian Predictive Distributions, URL (v: 2018-08-19): https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/335496 and excerpted here:

> Now, how do we obtain the samples from p(y~|y)? The method you describe is sometimes called the **method of composition**, which works as follows:
>
> > for NewSimulatedData = 1,2,...,s do
> >
> > > draw θ(s) from p(θ|y)  #This is the MCMC sample of the PPD from JAGS
> > >       draw y~(s) from p(y~|θ(s)) #This draws a simulated dataset from a PPD
>
> where, in most situations, we have already the draws from p(θ|y), so that only the second step is required.

As a side note: I have not done this second step in JAGS either as I had not found an example of how to do this so I just took the 100,000 θ(s) from p(θ|y) and generated the y~(s) to serve input into the larger equation.

**Step 1**

I have made 4 separate JAGS models to generate Posterior Predictive Distributions for each stochastic variable:

1. One for estimating parameters needed to generate a PPD for variable G;
2. One for estimating parameters needed to generate a PPD for "avoid";
3. One for estimating P (Slope), R (Intercept) parameters of a linear relationship and generating Q (X-values) to generate the expected values of Y;

Each of these JAGS models have the following:

```
#JAGS ITERATIONS
adaptSteps = 5000 #Number of steps to "tune" the samplers
burnInSteps = 50000 #Number of steps to "burn-in" the samplers
nChains = 4 #Number of steps to "burn-in" the samplers
thinSteps = 5 #Number of steps to "thin" (1=keep every step)
numSavedSteps = 100000 #Total number of steps in chains to save
nPerChain = ceiling( ( numSavedSteps * thinSteps ) / nChains ) #Steps per chain
```

Here is the JAGS model and code to implement it for:

1. G:

```
 #JAGS MODEL CODE FOR G
modelString = "
model {

#Likelihood function: Log-normal
#Note that JAGS uses precision as scale parameter for log-normal distributions rather than variance (which is the inverse of precision) 
    for( i in 1 : N ) {
      y[i] ~ dlnorm( muOfLogY , 1/sigmaOfLogY^2 ) 
    }

#Prior for mu of log(y): Normal distribution with a location parameter matching mean of log(y) of flight speed with a large spread about the location 
  muOfLogY ~ dnorm( meanOfLogY , 1/(10*sdOfLogY)^2 ) 

#Prior for sigma of log(y): Uniform distribution with a wide range that included all probable values of variance for flight speed 
  sigmaOfLogY ~ dunif( 0.001*sdOfLogY , 1000*sdOfLogY )  

#Prior for Mu: Not essential for calculations of collision risk but tracked so that parameter distributions could be viewed on a non-logarithmic scale (more intuitive)
  muOfY <- exp( muOfLogY+sigmaOfLogY^2/2 )

#Prior for Mode: Not essential for calculations of collision risk but tracked so that parameter distributions could be viewed on a non-logarithmic scale (more intuitive)
  modeOfY <- exp( muOfLogY-sigmaOfLogY^2 )

#Prior for Sigma: Not essential for calculations of collision risk but tracked so that parameter distributions could be viewed on a non-logarithmic scale (more intuitive)
  sigmaOfY <- sqrt( exp(2*muOfLogY+sigmaOfLogY^2)*(exp(sigmaOfLogY^2)-1) )
#-----------------
#References:
#Code adapted from Krushcke (2015): Doing Bayesian Data Analysis-A Tutorial with R, JAGS, and Stan (Jags-Ymet-Xnom1grp-MlogNormal-Script.R) 
}
" # close quote for modelString
writeLines( modelString , con="JAGS_C1.txt" )

#PARAMETERS TO TRACK
parameters = c("muOfLogY" , "sigmaOfLogY" , "muOfY" , "modeOfY" , "sigmaOfY" ) 

# CREATE, INITIALIZE, AND ADAPT THE MODEL:
jagsModel = jags.model( "JAGS_C1.txt" , data=dataList ,
                        n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps )
# BURN IN THE MCMC CHAIN:
cat( "Burning in the MCMC chain...\n" )
update( jagsModel , n.iter=burnInSteps )

# SAVE MCMC CHAIN:
cat( "Sampling final MCMC chain...\n" )
mcmcCoda1 = coda.samples( jagsModel , variable.names=parameters ,
                            n.iter=nPerChain , thin=thinSteps )
```

2. avoid:

```
#JAGS MODEL FOR AVOID
#-----------------
modelString = "
model {

#Likelihood function: Weibull
#Note that the parameterization of this distribution by JAGS and R(dweibul) use different notation/parameters
#Shape parameter: JAGS is 'nu', R(dweibul) is 'a'
#Scale parameter: JAGS is 'lambda', R(dweibul) is 'b'
  for ( i in 1:N ) {
    y[i] ~ dweib( nu , lambda )  #This is the JAGS parameterization of Weibull distribution
   }

#Prior for nu: Uniform distribution that included all probable values of the shape parameter
  nu <- a   #Renaming parameter to match R language rather than JAGS language (more intuitive)
  a ~ dunif( 0,200 )

#Prior for lambda: Uniform distribution that included all probable values of the scale parameter
  lambda <- 1/b^a #Put parameter in terms of R language rather than JAGS language (more intuitive)
  b ~ dunif(0,200)  

#-----------------
#References:
#Code adapted from Krushcke (2015): Doing Bayesian Data Analysis-A Tutorial with R, JAGS, and Stan (Jags-YmetCensored-Xnom2grp-Mweibull.R) 
}
" # close quote for modelString
writeLines( modelString , con="JAGS_C2.txt" )


#PARAMETERS TO TRACK
parameters = c("nu","a","b")
nPerChain = ceiling( ( numSavedSteps * thinSteps ) / nChains ) # Steps per chain.

# CREATE, INITIALIZE, AND ADAPT THE MODEL:
jagsModel = jags.model( "JAGS_C2.txt" , data=dataList ,
                        n.chains=nChains , n.adapt=adaptSteps )
# BURN IN THE MCMC CHAIN:
cat( "Burning in the MCMC chain...\n" )
update( jagsModel , n.iter=burnInSteps )

# SAVE MCMC CHAIN:
cat( "Sampling final MCMC chain...\n" )
mcmcCoda2 = coda.samples( jagsModel, variable.names=parameters ,
                            n.iter=nPerChain, thin=thinSteps,                                                          
                            method="parallel" )
```

3. P, Q, R and derived Y: For simplicity, we'll skip the JAGS code for #3 as it is probably not needed to make this a reproducible example. It is an adapted version of the code provided by John Kruschke and available here http://doingbayesiandataanalysis.blogspot.com/2015/10/posterior-predicted-distribution-for.html.

**Step 2**

The outcome of each JAGS model is saved as "mcmcCODA" which contains 100,000 steps (or samples) of the parameters that determine the shape/scale/location of the Posterior Predictive Distribution. I use these to generate new data from the PPD to serve as inputs to the larger equation.

## For purposes of a reproducible example

Let's say the equation was considerably simplified, with just stochastic variables 1 and 2 and one additional deterministic variable so the equation would be something like:

> *Outcome = StochasticVar1 * (1-StochasticVar2) * DeterministicVar1*

**Would the best approach to be something as follows?**

```
#INTEGRATED JAGS MODEL
#-----------------
modelString = "
model {
### Main equation ###
outcome <- SV1 * (1 - SV2) * DV1

### Likelihoods ###

#Likelihood function for G: Log-normal
#Note that JAGS uses precision as scale parameter for log-normal distributions rather than variance (which is the inverse of precision) 
    for( i in 1 : N ) {
      y[i] ~ dlnorm( muOfLogY , 1/sigmaOfLogY^2 ) 
    }


#Likelihood function for "avoid": Weibull
#Note that the parameterization of this distribution by JAGS and R(dweibul) use different notation/parameters
#Shape parameter: JAGS is 'nu', R(dweibul) is 'a'
#Scale parameter: JAGS is 'lambda', R(dweibul) is 'b'
  for ( i in 1:N ) {
    y[i] ~ dweib( nu , lambda )  #This is the JAGS parameterization of Weibull distribution
   }

### Priors ###

#All the priors from above JAGS code
```

The most complicated JAGS/BUGS model I have located so far is from Pardo et al (2015) https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0120727 and their supplemental code https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0120727.s002 that I have reproduced here:

```
##### Short-beaked common dolphins: #####
  ##### PRIORS: #####
  a0 ~ dunif(-0.2,0.6)        
  a1 ~ dunif(-0.3,-0.02)       
  a2 ~ dunif(0.05,0.42)         
  sd.eps.a ~ dunif(0.15,0.65)   
  sd.eps.a2 ~ dunif(0.05,0.42)  
  logmu.gs ~ dunif(3.5,5.5)     
  logsd.gs ~ dunif(8.5,13.5)    
  nu0 ~ dunif(-3.6,-2.1)         
  nu1 ~ dunif(-14,-7.5)             
  nu2 ~ dunif(-45,-18)           
  sd.eps.nu ~ dunif(1.12,1.95)   
  #### OBSERVATION MODELS ####
  ## Models from sightings (j): ##
  logvar.gs <- log(1+pow(logsd.gs/logmu.gs,2))  
  logtau.gs <- 1/logvar.gs   
  eps.a.tau <- 1/(sd.eps.a*sd.eps.a) 
  for (j in 1:1723){
    perp.dist.sigh[j] ~ dnorm(0,perp.dist.tau[j]) # Eq. 1
    perp.dist.tau[j] <- 1/(pow(w.sigh[j],2)*(2/pi)) # Eq. 2
    gp.sz.sigh[j] ~ dlnorm(logmu.gs,logtau.gs) # Eq. 4
    eps.a[j] ~ dnorm(0,eps.a.tau)                   
    w.sigh[j] <- exp(a0+(a1*beauf.sigh[j])+(a2*log(gp.sz.sigh[j]))+eps.a[j]) # Eq. 6
  }
  mean.gs <- exp(logmu.gs+0.5*logvar.gs) # Eq. 7
  #### g(0): ####
  g0.barlow ~ dbeta(102.8362,3.180502) # Eqs. 13 to 16
  #### Models from cells (i): ####
  eps.a2.tau <- 1/(sd.eps.a2*sd.eps.a2)
  eps.nu.tau <- 1/(sd.eps.nu*sd.eps.nu)
  for (i in 1:11173)
    #### Effective strip half-width model for cells: ####
    eps.a2[i] ~ dnorm(0,eps.a2.tau) 
    w.cell[i] <-exp(a0+(a1*beauf.cell[i])+(a2*log(mean.gs))+eps.a2[i]) # Eq. 9
    ## Predicted group counts: ##
    n.groups.cell[i] ~ dpois(pred.gp[i]) # Eq. 10
    pred.gp[i] <- (2*w.cell[i]*eff.cell[i]*dens.cell[i]*g0.barlow)/mean.gs # Eq. 12
    #### Check the group counts likelihood: ####
    squared.res.obs.gp.counts[i] <- pow(n.groups.cell[i]-pred.gp[i],2)                   
    new.n.groups.cell[i] ~ dpois(pred.gp[i])                                              
    new.squared.res.gp.counts[i] <- pow(new.n.groups.cell[i] - pred.gp[i], 2)
    ###################################### ECOLOGICAL MODEL: ######################################
    eps.nu[i] ~ dnorm(0,eps.nu.tau)
    dens.cell[i] <- exp(nu0+(nu1*ssh.cells[i])+(nu2*pow(ssh.cells[i],2))+eps.nu[i]) # Eq. 17
  }
  #### POSTERIOR PREDICTIVE CHECK: ####
  fit.obs.counts <- sum(squared.res.obs.gp.counts[]) 
  fit.new.counts <- sum(new.squared.res.gp.counts[])
  test.fit.counts <- step(fit.new.counts-fit.obs.counts)
  b.p.value.counts <- mean(test.fit.counts) # Bayesian p-value
```

## Main point

I feel like I am missing something fundamental. Any advice, resources, or expertise that exists to help create a single integrated model or any thoughts on the most appropriate approach given the situation would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry you haven't gotten much feedback here. The [Stan](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/) or [PyMC3](https://discourse.pymc.io/) Discourse forums might be better places to discuss such Bayesian model formulation questions, although it might entail you switching to one of those frameworks. I don't know of any equivalents for JAGS users, and sort of get the sense that it's an outdated framework to be using.

Comment: Thanks @merv, your advice is greatly appreciated and I have spent a lot of time looking through those forums and will also reach out there as needed. I heavily edited this post in an attempt to make the question more approachable in this forum.